# Cannot install dependencies from install_requires

Tags: python, pip, tox

I want to have the following dependcies in my `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[

        'pcapy>=0.10.0',
    ],
    ...
)
```

But `pcapy` cannot be loaded using `tox`:

```
GLOB sdist-make: /home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/setup.py
py27 create: /home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27
py27 installdeps: setuptools>=5.4.1, nose>=1.3.0
py27 inst: /home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/dist/scapy-2.2.0-dev.zip
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: Unpacking ./.tox/dist/scapy-2.2.0-dev.zip
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-3RpF94-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/dist/scapy-2.2.0-dev.zip 
...    
Downloading/unpacking pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pcapy>=0.10.0 (from     scapy==2.2.0-dev)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kartoch/.pip/pip.log
```

Whatever is the solution, this is at each time the same problem.

By default, it does not want to load the 0.10.3 version from pypi (see pip log below).

If I use the dependency_links pointing to latest version at github,

```
setup(
   ...
    install_requires=[
        'pcapy==0.10.8',
    ],
   dependency_links = ['http://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy/tarball/master#egg=0.10.8']
   ...
)
```

The same pip log is returned.

Any idea ?

PS1: PIP is called with the followiçng command by `tox`

```
install_command = pip install --allow-external pcapy --allow-unverified pcapy {opts} {packages}
```

PS2: The PIP log error

```
Downloading/unpacking pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/
  URLs to search for versions for pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.3.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/); unknown archive format: .html
  Getting page http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.3.tar.gz
  Skipping page http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.3.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pcapy/) because of Content-Type: application/binary
  Getting page http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html
  Analyzing links from page http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=area (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=project (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=researcher (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=publication (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=advisory (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=tool (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=list&type=brainstorming (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://www.tcpdump.org/ (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Impacket (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.8.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.8.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.7.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.7.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.6.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.6.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.5.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.5.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.3.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.2.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.2.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.8.win32-py2.5.exe (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.6.win32-py2.5.exe (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.5.win32-py2.5.exe (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.4.win32-py2.4.exe (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/ (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://gcc.gnu.org (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://winpcap.polito.it/ (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); not a file
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-doc.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=500043 (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .cgi
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=page&name=Pcapy.LICENSE (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file= (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.4.tar.gz (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.4.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-stable.zip (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=WPSIG (from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy); unknown archive format: .php
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27/build...
No distributions at all found for pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/home/kartoch/Documents/works/python/scapy/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pcapy>=0.10.0 (from scapy==2.2.0-dev)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `requirements.txt` solves the problem:

```
pycrypto>=2.6.0
https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy/tarball/0.10.8
```